# How can I find all copies of an executable name in my PATH?

Tags: bash, path

I was looking for a way to enumerate all copies of an executable that are shadowed by the first one in my `PATH`. The best I could come up with is a function:

```
find_all_exec() { 
    for i in ${PATH//:/ }; do
        find "$i/$1" 2> /dev/null
    done
}

$ find_all_exec python
/usr/local/bin/python
/usr/bin/python
```

This gets me what I want (though it doesn't handle bash aliases/functions as `type` does). I was curious if there's a more built in way?

Comment: Some people may Google search and land on this page who are actually looking for this: [Unix & Linux: List all binaries from `$PATH`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/120825/114401)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Try this command:

```
which -a python
```

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I was looking for. Guess I should RTFM a bit more.

Comment: what shell is that built into? Not bash version 4.2.45(1)-release: `type which` -> `which is /usr/bin/which`. For bash: `type -a python`

Comment: good point @glennjackman actually `which` isn't a builtin command, but as you know usually it's provided along with bash. Anyway, `type -a` provides me a different output from what I expect, showing me just an occurrence of an executable existing in tho different paths. Do you know why?

Comment: I figured that making it the default behaviour might break some scripts I use, so I aliased it in my `~/.bashrc` as `alias whichall='which -a $*'`

Answer (score 7):

```
type -a *
```

For example,

```
type -a python
```

gives

```
python is /Users/user1/anaconda3/bin/python
python is /usr/local/bin/python
python is /usr/bin/python
python is /Applications/CASA.app/Contents/MacOS/python
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this should work:

```
IFS=:
for dir in $PATH; do
    if [ -x "$dir/$1" ]
    then echo "$dir/$1"
    fi
done
```